# php execute local jar file from linux server

Tags: java, php, server, local

I'm developing a little software that is written in php and run on linux server...
I need that on one client (windows with java installed) I can run a jar file

```
exec("java -jar myfile.jar")
```

because on this client I have a serial connection that I can use with java...

The jar file is already on the client machine

Is there a possibility to run this exec on local (windows) machine?

Comment: No idea what you are asking. What are you asking? How to transmit a JAR file? How to make sure that the local side has a java installed?

Comment: yes, client with windows has java installed

Comment: where is your php script running ?? remote linux server ( apache) ?
& you want to run jar file of client accessing it via browser reading jar file from browser client's disk ? explain these please !

Comment: Yes, php run on apache server and I need to run the script (as above) from browser client

Answer (score 0):

Try using Absolute path and shell_exec, set java path

```
shell_exec(' "c:/program files/oracle/jdk/bin/java.exe" -jar "d:/path/myfile.jar"');
```

Comment: Not working... Seems that it can't find my file (or can't connect?) on local disk because also if I check with php function file_exist("d:/path/myfile.jar") return error

Comment: You have to mention specific directory. I just added for example "d:/path/" . and set environment variable for Java installed in your system and call. It works

Comment: Not working because the program runs on a linux server, not on local... The program runs on "192.168.1.xx/myprogram/"

And I need to run a local execution

Comment: In that case try on your linux server 

shell_exec("java -jar myfile.jar")

Comment: Yes, in this case works, but I nedd to run java file on local because I have rs232 connected on local machine not on the server

Comment: That is what I mentioned earlier posts Shell_exec(your local java exe file  -jar  your file)

Comment: As I said, not working... I know that "d:/path" was an example, then if I check file_exist("c:/Windows") I get error...